# Y a-t-il un mot pour désigner l'utilisation de niveaux de langues différents au sein d'une phrase ?

Tags: vocabulaire, registre, niveau-de-langue

Existe-t-il un mot pour désigner le fait d'utiliser, au sein d'une même phrase, plusieurs registres ou niveaux de langue différents ?

Par exemple, employer un mot soutenu dans une phrase par ailleurs familière, ou, au contraire, un terme argotique dans une phrase d'un registre soutenu.

Comment: (+1) Merci pour cette excellente question! J'ai cherché du côté du zeugma, de la syllepse, mais ce n'est pas ça... Impatient de voir les réponses.

Answer (score 7):

Il ne me vient pas à l'esprit de mot qui exprimerait cela. Je pense que l'expression la plus claire est *mélange de registres*.

Answer (score 7):

[*Alternance codique*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternance_de_code_linguistique) (en anglais *code-switching*) et *changement de style* (en anglais [*style-shifting*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style-shifting)) sont les termes qui me viennent en tête au premier abord.

Answer (score 6):

Je dirais que de tels propos ou mots [détonnent](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9tonner) (avec deux *n*, aucun danger). Ce n'est probablement pas suffisant pour comprendre qu'il s'agit de la forme plutôt que du fond, mais c'est un début.

Deux autres propositions : des mots qui jurent, ou des propos dépareillés.

Comment: "avec deux n, aucun danger" :) Bravo !

Answer (score 0):

Il semblerait qu'il n'y ait pas de mot académique pour signifier ce **mélange de style**.

L'***[incise](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition_incise)*** dans une phrase peut avoir un style différent pour soutenir l'intention ou la signification de la période visée

> Monsieur Jules, chef comptable respecté de tous, arrivé chez lui laissa exploser sa colère : "Merde alors ! Ces cons ont encore salopé mon mur !" ; se ressaisissant, il se dit "Demain je solliciterai les services municipaux pour qu'ils effacent ces infâmes et inesthétiques gribouillis".